# Tried to install VITE to use React but its returning npm ERR

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

This is the NPM error its returning on my terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\hp pavilion\Desktop\bank_modern_app> npm create vite@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hp pavilion\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-25T12_33_45_682Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\hp pavilion\Desktop\bank_modern_app>
```

I tried installing VITE to use React using "npm create vite@latest" but its returning npm ERROR.

I intend to use install React using VITE. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps:

```
$ npm config set proxy http://your.proxy.url:port
$ npm config set https-proxy http://your.proxy.url:port
```

The issue might be due to a corrupted npm cache. Try clearing the cache:

```
$ npm cache clean -f
$ npm install -g npm@latest
$ npm create vite@latest
```